# Disconnect from wifi on windows 10 lock

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

i want my windows 10 to disconnect from WiFi immediately when i hit windows+L and lock it. don't want it to turn off WiFi just disconnect from any connected networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disconnect from all connected networks, use the `netsh` command like this:

```
netsh wlan disconnect
```

You can put this command in a `.bat` script and use the Task Scheduler
to create a task that uses the trigger "On workstation lock"
and defined as "Run with highest privileges".

This will run automatically whenever you do
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a batch file with the commands:

```
netsh wlan disconnect interface="name of connection"
rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkstation
```

Reference for locking the workstation : [Lock workstation](https://www.howtogeek.com/686575/how-to-lock-your-windows-10-pc-using-command-prompt/)

You can also disconnect (as above) as a single batch file line, and then use the standard lock function.